# "Occupied" as "employed"?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

I came across two similar instances of *occupy* that I don't really understand.

> The large industrial population of the town is **occupied in** the manufacture of lace, which extended hither from Nottingham; there are also railway carriage works. ([Your Dictionary Sentence](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/occupied))
>
> a person or thing **occupied** in or designed for splitting something. (Google's definition of "splitter")

It seems *occupied* in both sentences mean **employed**, but I can't find any dictionaries that support this (checked MW and ODO). The closest usage I could find is *to hold a position or a job*, which is not the same. Intuitively, it would make sense that *occupy* could have usages related to *occupation*. But why can't I find it in the dictionaries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**are occupied in {X}** could be paraphrased as "have {X} as their occupation (job)" or "have an occupation (job) that is in some way related to {X}".

This locution is generally reserved for contexts where one is speaking demographically, speaking of particular groups of people in a population.  A *single person* would not typically say "I am occupied in the manufacture of lace".

https://www.google.com/search?q=%22were%20occupied%20in%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: This answer makes much more sense. It does seem a somewhat uncommon usage.

Comment: @L.Moneta "uncommon"? Have you checked the link? There are hundreds of books with that expression.

Comment: You are both right.  It is, as RubioRic says, very well attested. But it isn't a colloquial way of stating the fact either; you tend to find it as I said in demographic/historical/sociological  contexts.  *In West Virginia, a large percentage of the population is occupied in the mining of coal.*

Comment: @RubioRic I see your point. But I did say "somewhat", didn't I? Kudos for locating _employed_ in the synonym list on the ODO. But your answer's main problem is you've failed to see the difference between the standard definition and my cited usage. I hope in the very least you can see an active/passive distinction. As Tᴚoɯɐuo points out, the usage is not the most common colloquial usage that most learners are familiar with.

Comment: Don't get too preoccupied with **occupy** or you will go down a rabbit-hole.

Answer (score 2):

[**Occupied**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/occupied):

> to engage the attention or energies of · They occupied themselves with
>   video games.

In your first sentence, it's reasonable to assume that most of the people are actually being paid to make lace, but, logically, that doesn't have to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to enlarge your search a bit.

**[occupy](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/occupy)**

> 1.3 Hold (a position or job)
>
> ‘a very different job from any that he had occupied before’

According to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/hold)

**hold** verb (CONTROL)

> to have something, especially a position or money, or to control something:
>
> He currently holds the position of technical manager.

[**occupation**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/occupation)

> A job or profession.

According to **[Oxford Theasurus](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/occupied)**

Synonyms of [**occupied**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/occupied): working, **employed**, at work, on the job, hard-pressed, active

After all these [evidences](https://blogg.lnu.se/english-language-blog/blog/magnus/is-evidence-used-in-the-plural/) plus the link offered by @Tᴚoɯɐuo, one may conclude that **occupy in a job** is the same as **being employed**, without any semantinc difference.

Comment: Well, that's what I said in the question. Glad you included the example sentence. The problem here is that if you look at the ODO's sentence, it is _People occupy a job_, Compare that to the sentences I quoted, which say _People **are occupied** in a job._ It's not simply a difference between active and passive voices, but also a difference on both syntactic and semantic levels.

Comment: @L.Moneta I don't get you. "It seems occupied in both sentences mean employed, but I can't find any dictionaries that support this" I've found evidences.

Comment: No, you didn't. You didn't provide any information beyond what I already said in my question. I said _The closest usage I could find is to hold a position or a job_

Comment: Plus, keep in mind that **evidence** is a noncount noun. So it's not **evidences***

Comment: @L.Moneta https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118727/is-evidence-countable I'm not so sure. Maybe it's old-fashioned but it is not incorrect.

Comment: @L.Moneta Have you checked my third link? occupied = employed [Oxford Thesaurus]